# Javascript-only wordwrap function on whitespace?

Tags: javascript

Most wordwrap functions I've found are bound to css and/or a browser dom.
I'm working in a javascript environment (rhino) and need to find or design a better word wrap that breaks on whitespace before a given line length value.
My current solution just searches for the last white space before the given character, then clips  the left side, storing it as a line of output (in an array return).  Repeat until no more text remains.

Hoping someone has seen something elegant.

Comment: not hosted in a browser.

Answer (score 5):

You could write something like:

```
let wordwrapped = (original + ' ').replace(/(\S(.{0,78}\S)?)\s+/g, '$1\n').trim();
```

That will replace `\s+` with `\n` after at-least-one,-at-most-eighty,-preferably-as-many-as-possible characters. (Note: if there are more than eighty characters in a row without whitespace, then there will be a line-break before and after them, but no wrapping will take place inside them.)

See it in action:

```js
// generate random sequence of 500 letters and spaces:
let original = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, Array.from({length: 500}, () => 64 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 27))).replace(/@/g, ' ');

// perform word-wrapping:
let wordwrapped = (original + ' ').replace(/(\S(.{0,78}\S)?)\s+/g, '$1\n').trim();

// show the results in the <pre> elements:
document.getElementById('ruakh-original').innerText = 'original:\n' + original;
document.getElementById('ruakh-word-wrapped').innerText = 'word-wrapped:\n' + wordwrapped;
```

```html
<pre id="ruakh-original"></pre>
<pre id="ruakh-word-wrapped"></pre>
```

Comment: I like the use of `replace`.  I had toyed with `split` but settled for `exec`.

Comment: It is dependant of a space at the end.

Comment: If you don't have a space at the end of `original`, the regexp will not include the last word.

Comment: You should explain how it works it your answer. Anyways, I created a website describing and demonstrating your regular expression [here](https://typescript-mssipm.stackblitz.io/)

Comment: So what you're saying is that the list of things I assumed was wrong in the linked website was all intended features?

Comment: No need to apologize. I'm sorry the website didn't work. I see you fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

This regex will wrap every 0-width character and respect whitespaces and hyphens also cuts words longer than width characters. Try it out on [regexr](https://regexr.com/5s1m5).

```js
/**
 * Wrap every 0-`width` character and respect whitespaces and hyphens also cuts words longer than `width` characters.
 * @param str The string to wrapped
 * @param width The maximum length a string can be
 */
function wordwrap(str, width) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(`(?:\\S(?:.{0,${width}}\\S)?(?:\\s+|-|$)|(?:\\S{${width}}))`, 'g'), s => `${s}\n`).slice(0, -1);
}
```

```js
function wordwrap(str, width) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp('(?:\\S(?:.{0,' + width + '}\\S)?(?:\\s+|-|$)|(?:\\S{' + width + '}))', 'g'), function (s) {return s + '\n'}).slice(0, -1);
}

console.log(wordwrap('This is my regular-expression. It will wrap every 0-20 character and respect whitespaces and hyphens, also cuts reallylongwordslikethis.', 20));
```

Answer (score -2):

RegEx is really the way to go. `/.{0,79}(?:\s|$)/g` will grab the longest line under 80 characters ending with a character or the end of the file.  Calling `exec` multiple times will extract each line.

```
var text = "";
var regex = /.{0,79}(?:\s|$)/g;
var lines = [];
var line;

while (line = regex.exec(text)) {
    lines.push(line);
}
```